# Very slow sockets on Android over wifi

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, wifi

I'm having a performance problem with the consistent speed of a tcp socket connection between 2 android tablets talking over WiFi on the same LAN. Occasionally (just enough to be real problem), round-trripping a small payload (< 1400 bytes) between devices can take *many* seconds.  It's not uncommon for it to take **10+ seconds**,  and in the worst case, I've seen a round trip time of **4 minutes.**  The socket is not broken - it's typically blocking on the read operation at the client or server end, and once the round trip finally completes, the next one could take just a few milliseconds.

If I continuously push data through the socket, then I do not see any problems, and it will typically remain fast ( < 100ms) and connected all day long.  However, when I drip feed payloads - say one every couple of seconds, then not only does each round trip take longer, but occasionally, I see these silly times of 10 seconds or more.  I'm not looking for high performance, and anything up to 3 seconds is not really a problem.

I understand that with pauses between payloads, Android will preserve battery by briefly turning off the WiFi radio, and the TCP stack may also add a small delay to give the app layer time to add a bit more data to the payload. These 2 points easily explain the ~120ms rountrips versus the 1-5ms roundtrips when payloads are sent continuously.  However, I've never heard of TCP hanging onto buffered data for 30+ seconds before sending.

This is not the Nagle issue - TCP_NO_DELAY is set to true, and I've played with thread priorities and other TCP tuning flags to no avail.

I'm using 2 Samsung Galaxy Tabs running Lollipop and Marshmallow, though I have also tried Asus, Archos, Lenovo and Huawei devices.

There's nothing fancy going on - writing to the socket looks like this:

```
try {
    clientSocket = new Socket(serverIp, ECHO_PORT);
    SocketTransport transport = new SocketTransport(clientSocket);

    while (running) {
        // Blocking call ;-)
        onStatusChange("Waiting for next message", 0);
        String msg = theQ.take();

        onStatusChange("Writing new message", 0);

        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        transport.write(msg);

        onStatusChange("Waiting for response", 0);
        String result = transport.read();

        onStatusChange(result, System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart);

        if (result == null) {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

with the actual read & writing happening in a simple wrapper class that looks like this:

```
package com.problem.sockettester;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * wrap up the reading and writing to sockets.
 */
public class SocketTransport {

    static final int IPTOS_LOWCOST = 0x02;
    static final int IPTOS_RELIABILITY = 0x04;
    static final int IPTOS_THROUGHPUT = 0x08;
    static final int IPTOS_LOWDELAY = 0x10;

    private DataInputStream reader;
    private DataOutputStream writer;

    private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

    public SocketTransport(Socket socket) throws IOException {

        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setTrafficClass(IPTOS_LOWDELAY | IPTOS_RELIABILITY);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
        socket.setSendBufferSize(4096);

        reader = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        writer = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    }

    public String read() throws IOException {

        int messageSize = reader.readInt();
        int bytesRead;
        int totalRead = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        boolean moreToRead = true;

        while (moreToRead) {
            bytesRead = reader.read(readBuffer, offset, messageSize);
            totalRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalRead == messageSize) {
                moreToRead = false;
            }

            offset += bytesRead;
        }

        return new String(readBuffer, 0, messageSize);
    }


    public int write(String message) throws IOException {

        writer.writeInt(message.length());
        writer.writeBytes(message);
        writer.flush();
        return message.length();
    }
}
```

For those that like a challenge, the full source of the minimal server and client apps that can be found on github at https://github.com/NigelDyson/androidsocketissue

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated - I'm fast running out of ideas.

Comment: Isn't there a return value for writeBytes()?

Comment: Why would the length() of a String, the amount of characters,  be equal to an amount of bytes?

Comment: @greenapps - writeBytes on DataOutputStream does not return a value, and it sneakily throws away the high 8 bits of each char in the string effectively making string length and byte count equal.  Thought, you had something there, but I suspect nothing would have worked if the byte counts were that far out.  Thanks for the feedback - I'll try something at the raw byte level to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Nige I know this thread is quite old, but did you ever get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: @ThomasSunderland - (equally late response) Sadly not - though it is no longer a problem for me as I'm in  a different role.  This was perhaps the only time the StackOverflow community failed to come up with a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Nige No worries! I think your comment about "If I continuously push data through the socket, then I do not see any problems..." helped us quite a bit. We ended up just creating a continuous ping task to keep the socket connection fast. It is still very strange behaviour and only observed on some Android devices, but this proved to be an effective workaround for the issue.

Comment: @Nige did you found a solution for this?